# Display a particular RFID tag count once if it is in range continously?

Tags: c#, tags, rfid

I want to modify my RFID reader in a way that whenever a tag is in range, it reads it and displays count. The problem is when the tag is in range it continuously reads the tag and increases the count multiple times?

I just placed a single tag for 30 seconds and it just read it 180 times. Code is in C sharp. Tag i am reading is EPC GEN 2;

```
        void EPCMultiTagInventory()
        {
            int TagCount = 0;
            int CntGot = 0;
            int GetCount = 0;
            int i, j = 0;
            int status;
            string EPC = "";
            BufferData[] Data = new BufferData[1024];
            for (int index = 0; index < Data.Length; index++)
            {
                Data[index].Data = new byte[512];
            }

            status = rfid_sp.GEN2_MultiTagInventory(CS, ref TagCount, 0xFF);
            if (0x00 == status)
            {
                while (CntGot < TagCount)
                {
                        status = rfid_sp.BufferM_GetTagData(CS, ref GetCount, Data, 0xFF);
                        if (0x00 == status)
                        {
                            if (GetCount <= 0)
                            {
                                break;
                            }

                            for (i = 0; i < GetCount; i++)
                            {
                                EPC = string.Format("{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}{3:X2}{4:X2}{5:X2}{6:X2}{7:X2}{8:X2}{9:X2}{10:X2}{11:X2}",
                                    Data[i].Data[0], Data[i].Data[1], Data[i].Data[2], Data[i].Data[3],
                                    Data[i].Data[4], Data[i].Data[5], Data[i].Data[6], Data[i].Data[7],
                                    Data[i].Data[8], Data[i].Data[9], Data[i].Data[10], Data[i].Data[11]);
                                if (SHOWDATA_listView.Items.Count <= 0)
                                {
                                    EPCDisplayNewTag(EPC);
                                    DisplayCnt++;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    int flg = -1;
                                    for (j = 0; j < SHOWDATA_listView.Items.Count; j++)
                                    {
                                        if (EPC == SHOWDATA_listView.Items[j].SubItems[1].Text)
                                        {
                                            SHOWDATA_listView.Items[j].SubItems[2].Text =
                                                Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(SHOWDATA_listView.Items[j].SubItems[2].Text) + 1);
                                            flg = i;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if (flg < 0)
                                    {
                                        EPCDisplayNewTag(EPC);
                                        DisplayCnt++;
                                    }
                                }
                            } // for each item
                        } // if Get buffer success

                        CntGot += GetCount;
                } // while buffer not empty
            } // if inventory success
        }
```

```
    void EPCDisplayNewTag(string strEpc)
    {
        string SN = "";
        if (OperationType == "Inventory" || OperationType == "Write")
        {
            SN = string.Format("{0:D}", DisplayCnt + 1);
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(SN);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(strEpc);
            lvi.SubItems.Add("1");
            SHOWDATA_listView.Items.Add(lvi);
            SHOWDATA_listView.EnsureVisible(SHOWDATA_listView.Items.Count - 1);
        }
        if (OperationType == "Read")
        {
            SN = string.Format("{0:D}", DisplayCnt + 1);
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(SN);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(RStr);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(EStr);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(TStr);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(UStr);
            lvi.SubItems.Add("1");
            lvi.SubItems.Add(strEpc);
            SHOWDATA_listView.Items.Add(lvi);
            SHOWDATA_listView.EnsureVisible(SHOWDATA_listView.Items.Count - 1);
        }
        NUMBER_label.Text = SN;
    }
```

```
            if (MULTITAG_INVENTORY_radioButton.Checked)
            {
                TempStr = "¿ªÊ¼²éÑ¯!";
                TempStrEnglish = "Start query!";
                EPC_OperationTime_timer.Enabled = true;
                EPC_MultiTagInventory_timer.Interval = timer;
                EPC_MultiTagInventory_timer.Enabled = true;
            }
```

Comment: Would reading "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)" help?